# Cross domain uploading , upload files from one domain on another domain

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

how to allow one domain to access another domain for uploading files from domain1 on domain2?
I have a page on domain1 from where users upload images but I want that the images get uploaded on a folder on domain2.com like domain2.com/uploads.

How do to allow domain1 to access domain2?

Comment: Generally its not restricted. Just set the <form action> value to your <domain2>. What makes you think its not working or not allowed?

Comment: I am checking that whether the upload directory exists , if not , then create new ,so I use mkdir (DirectoryName , 0700 ) , but this gives error

Comment: Of course you can not create directories at another server directly. Why not sending the uploaded files *directly* to the domain2? (as described in my previous account)

Comment: @MonkeyMonkey : sir , how would I be able to create directories

Comment: also , please help me with some example code about your first way of uploading files , changing form action ...

Comment: @MonkeyMonkey : sir ,if server is same , then can i create directories directly on another domain ?

Comment: You can create directories using the FILESYSTEM. So if both domains are on the same server: Yes, you can (just depending on your account's right)

Answer (score 1):

http://domain-A.org/send.php:

```
<form action="http://domain-B.org/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- .. -->
</form>
```

http://domain-B.org/upload.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
```

Comment: sir , how do I enable the user to create directories on domainB.org , from  domainA.org...   Same Server ---- please help me out with the RIGHTS  ? from where shall I give the rights .?

Comment: As said before, it doesnt matter if there are two vhosts or more. It all depends on the filesystem. If your domain A is at /home/www/domain-a/public and your domain B at /home/www/domain-b/public, then you can create a folder there with `mkdir('/home/www/where/ever/you/want')`. Please report the error messages if you already tried it.

Comment: sir,  actually , previously when the folder permissions on domainB were 755 then it wasn't working ? so i have to make it to 733 .....but 733 makes my folder open to whole world which i cant bear...as its not safe